# Cannot figure out catching thrown exception

Tags: php, exception

I am trying to use a try/catch block to add in some error handling for a custom WordPress plugin that gets Tweets via the Twitter API.

For testing purposes, I am throwing an exception in my class construct method.

```
class Twitter_Settings() {

    public function __construct() {
        throw new \Exception('test');
    }
}
```

then in my plugin file, I am doing:

```
function twitter_init_settings() {
    try {
        return new Twitter_Settings();
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

twitter_init_settings();
```

On the frontend, where I am spitting out `$tweets = twitter_feed()->output_feed();` (with a foreach loop afterwards) I am getting an Uncaught Exception error. Oddly, it shows the custom message, 'test', so it must know about my exception, so why is it saying it is uncaught?

Comment: Probably you instantiating `Twitter_Settings` object somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Uncaught Exception error happen while an exception is not catched (in try catch statements)

Remove the return statment because the catch might not be reached.